# How to add minutes to a DateTime and create a new dateTime? xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Im working with xamarin in visual studio and i ran into a problem:

I have a DateTime variable: for example: 2/17/2021 2:10:00 PM

and I also have an int variable that resembles minutes: for example: 154

I want to add the minutes to to the date, so I will get a new DateTime variable:

2/17/2021 4:44:00 PM (added 2 hours and 34 mintues (the 154 mintues))

Is there any method that does it for me? or I need to do it manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

use [AddMinutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addminutes?view=net-5.0)

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(now);
// 1/29/2021 9:52:59 AM

var x = 93;
var then = now.AddMinutes(x);
Console.WriteLine(then);
// 1/29/2021 11:25:59 AM
```

Comment: Ah, the old "didn't work" explanation.  If you want actual help, post your code so we can see what "didn't work".  We can't troubleshoot vague explanations...

Comment: Note that simply calling `AddMinutes()` does NOT change the original DateTime instance.  A new DateTime instance is RETURNED.  If you want to change the original variable, assign it to the result: `dt = dt.AddMinutes(x);`

Comment: OP said specifically "so I will get a new DateTime variable"

Comment: Absolutely Jason.  There's nothing wrong with your code (I upvoted it, in fact).  My comments were directed at OP who said it "didn't work".

Answer (score 0):

> I have a DateTime variable: for example: 2/17/2021 2:10:00 PM,and I also have an int variable that resembles minutes: for example: 154.I want to add the minutes to to the date, so I will get a new DateTime variable:

As Jason reply, I create datetime variable, then add minutes to this data to get new data.

```
        String strDate = "2/17/2021 2:10:00 AM";
        DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(date);
        //2/17/2021 2:10:00 AM

        var x = 154;
        var newdate = date.AddMinutes(x);
        Console.WriteLine(newdate);
        //2/17/2021 4:44:00 PM
```